# Are there any GUI test suites for Linux?

Tags: linux, software-rec, testing

I'm looking to automate some software testing that's currently done manually by a person. Are there any regression test suites for testing GUIs that run on Linux? I'm looking for a way to record and control an X Window's set of buttons, and to read log files to determine if the test is passing.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Did you try with R?

Comment: @fclad Not sure what R can do in this case, I'm talking about regression testing, not mathematics linear regression. P.S. Updated/Edited, let me know how i can it make more clear